# $http get Request executing many times in angular js in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm calling the function from laravel blade template but it is sending multiple requests that's make the browser unresponsive
**Here is my code**

```
 **Laravel View**
  <div ng-controller="HotelsListController as listCntrl">
     <section class="section section-sec top-hotels hotels-sec">
        <div class="container">
           {{ listCntrl.hotelsRequests() }}
         </div>
      </section>  
   </div>
```

**Angular JS **

```
   (function(){

       angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('HotelsListController',hotelsListController);

        hotelsListController.$inject = ['$http'];

        function hotelsListController($http){

           var vm =  this;
           vm.hotelsRequests = getHotelData;


        function getHotelData(){
           $http.get('/hotels/getHotelsRequest').then(function(response){
              console.log(response);
           });
      }
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use **ng-init** directive of AngularJS

```
 <div ng-controller="HotelsListController as listCntrl">
 <section class="section section-sec top-hotels hotels-sec" ng-init="hotelsRequests()">
    <div class="container">
     </div>
  </section>
```

As it will call your function  `getHotelData()`.

Happy coding :)

Comment: so i cannot use directly into my view like this {{ listCntrl.hotelsRequests() }}

Comment: It's a safe way to load function using ng-init. it will get render when you initialize page. an additional suggestion, you can write an angularJS part more feasible way. i.e. https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: This is not what `ng-init` is intended for. Should just call the method directly in controller and render the response in view by assigning to a controller property

Comment: Also should be `listCntrl.hotelsRequests()` since OP is using `controller as` syntax and the function itself needs to be modified as does what gets rendered